# Will merging assemblies into my executable affect application performance?

Tags: c#

Is a windows form application's performance affected in any way by the size of the .exe ? I'm thinking that it wouldn't make sense for it to be.

Comment: Is it abstract question or you're facing some concrete aplication performance issue? Then providing some samples would be helpful to understand your question.

Comment: Have a look at [Steps involved in the running of an exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600048/steps-involved-in-the-running-of-an-exe), same concept

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I have an application that has a lot of misc dlls. I was going to try and just include them in the exe, but I wanted to first be sure it wouldn't cause performance issues.

Comment: The answers are "it depends" and "measure it".

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg Making "solid" exe instead of "starter exe + bunch of modules in dlls" doesn't looks like a good idea for me. Not even from the point of view concerning performance - but what about modularity and flexibility?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev You're probably right - it was a thought I had that probably wont pan out.